# JSON schema for odd numbers

Tags: json, jsonschema

How to have a JSON schema to validate for odd positive integers? At first glance it seems impossible, but perhaps there's some trick?

Comment: Sorry but this is not possible with JSON Schema.

Comment: *seems not possible when you're pre-coffee... Ethan's answer is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this schema should work

```
type: integer
not:
  multipleOf: 2
minimum: 0
```

Comment: This seems work for even number, not odd number.

Comment: even would be `multipleOf: 2`. this specifies `not: {multipleOf: 2}`

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake. Thanks, this is very helpful